# Verofone VX520 how to write custom software

Tags: smartcard, verifone

I have vx520 one with pin-pad. The task is:

- Store virtual money (f.e. litres of fuel) on chip card
- Client can pay with it knowing his pin-code
- Terminal should be available to register and program new cards

Where do I start? Is there any kind of SDK for Verifone terminals? I found an ADK on the official site, but it needs license (their email doesn't work when I write to them). Is there any way to develop my own software without a license?

P.S. I'm using a "SLE4428" smart card--is that OK?

Comment: SLE4428 is a dumb memory card , which would need much ( cryptographic) effort on terminal or background system side to get  only very low security - duplicating a charged card could be easy if the amount is stored on the card. Verifone is unlikely to handle anything else but an EMV compliant smart card, so a contract with a card- issuing bank and non-disclosure agreements may also be needed there.

Comment: @guidot so is there any way to develop software without license?

Comment: Yes, Just remove the default VeriFone certificate and install your own so you can install your signed packages, and you are golden.

Comment: @FlexibleCoder how to do it? I am newbee in this thing. How do I generate certificates if I have to? How to download them to terminal? How to write software? Any APIs, SDKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  You don't typically store the data on the card itself.  Instead, you want to have the terminal read the card and send that data to a back-end server.  The server looks up the account based on the unique card data and returns back the balance, etc.  And, yes--you will need to develop your own software for this to work properly which will require a license.  In my experience, very little in the VeriFone world is ever free... or even cheap, for that matter.

Yes, there is an SDK, but you can't use it without a license.  If you are serious about your project and willing to purchase what you need, you can try and reach VeriFone through their main site [here](http://www.verifone.com/contact) or through their developer site, [here](https://www.verifonedevnet.com/verifone/devnet/dnProgramView.do?pageTypeId=109141&programPage=%2Fjsp%2Fdevnet%2Fprogram%2FdnTechContacts.jsp&programId=109171&channelId=-9086) to get started.

(Disclaimer: I don't use those contact routes because our company already has a VeriFone liaison of sorts, however I suspect either of the linked contact methods will work.)